# AutoLoad controller in subdirectory in Yii2 issue

Tags: yii2

I have subfolders "agent" and "admin" in controllers folder in Yii2.

When I type `localhost/projectname/agent/dashboard`, it runs fine, where "dashboard" is a controller in "agent" folder.

But when I type `localhost/projectname/agent` it says page not found. What is the solution to this? I also know this type of work should be handled in modules.

Answer (score 2):

Yii is looking for an `AgentController` in the main controllers directory with that second URL ("http://localhost/projectname/agent").

You can use custom URL rules to ensure it hits the `AgentController` in your "agent" folder instead. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules

Something like:

```
"agent" => "agent/index"
```

should do the trick. Make sure to change "index" to something else if you want a differently-named action to be called for that URL.

Comment: In web.php (urlManager ... rules) I added

[
 'pattern' => 'agent',
 'route' => 'agent/dashboard'
]

Comment: Now it works fine for "localhost/projectname/agent".
But when I add "/" at the end of URL it says page not found :-(

Comment: See this discussion: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1807 You can change the suffix an the UrlManager level (either slash or no slash) or you can define the route twice, once with the slash and once without it.

Comment: Thanks Alot ;-) Thumbs Up ... :-)

Comment: Great, glad to help. If you accept this as the answer to your question that would be great as well